# How can I display special chars in an alert box using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to display special chars as an alert box using javascript and jsp...

```
String encodeString = "ss\ncc";
String test = "DisplayNext('"+encodeString+"')";
String NextLink = "<br><a href='#' onclick="+test+"> Next</a>";
```

That is

```
function DisplayNext(Next){
   alert(Next);
}
```

Though I've used special chars I am not able to display them in an alert box. How can I sort this out?

Comment: You've posted **67** previous questions. With respect, you should be able to format code by now. See the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code produce something like this:

```
<br><a href='#' onclick="DisplayNext('ss
cc');"> Next</a>
```

And what you need is:

```
<br><a href='#' onclick="DisplayNext('ss\ncc');"> Next</a>
```

If you want a line break in javascript it must look as `\\n` in java. So use:

```
String encodeString = "ss\\ncc";
String test = "DisplayNext('"+encodeString+"')";
String NextLink = "<br><a href='#' onclick="+test+"> Next</a>";
```

Also consider using a special function to escape your String objects as javascript values. Google will easily help you find it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your String is URLEncoded in java you need to unescape it in javascript.

Java:

```
    String s = "ë";
    System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(s, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

this will print out %EB

Javascript:

```
alert(unescape('%EB'));
```

this will print out the character ë in alert message